# Why do I get a higher download speed if download via public domain on local computer?

Tags: windows-7, routing, webserver, bandwidth

I have set up a web-server on a computer and set a domain-name (e.g., `www.mydomain.com`) to point to the system’s public IP address.

I downloaded a file via the domain-name (e.g., `www.mydomain.com/file.zip`) on the same PC and got a speed of 700KBps. However, when I tried downloading the same file from my office a few kilometers away, I only got 100KBps, which is my normal upload speed.

I’m wondering if when I download a file on a PC via its public IP, does the ISP directly serve me the file because my maximum upload speed is 110KBps?

Comment: As the answers below have indicated, you are not getting the file from the Internet, the request is looping back and getting it from the hard-drive. Do you have an entry in your `HOSTS` file for that domain?  Do you have a router? Instead of getting the file using the domain-name, try getting it using its public IP (e.g., `http://1.2.3.4/file.zip`), does that transfer at 100KBps or 700KBps? (Also, are you sure about your units? Is it KBps or Kbps?)

Comment: @Synetech. The entry is `AWS Route 53` so its `FQDN` for my home server. The speed is `KB/s`. i remember fir first 10 seconds i get 10KB/s speed but then it increased to 700KB/s. I have the netgear router. i can't try the ip/file because my websever is set for named virtual hosts so it work display the site with domain name only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The As everything is on your network the packets never get routed to the ISP, so they don't see them.   As they don't go through your "Internet Connection", they are not throttled by that.

That said, 700KB/sec is very slow for something within the same lan, let alone the PC.

Comment: I am not sure why the LAN speed is very less. I have the router and have USB wireless adapter and inside that i have virtual machine. don't know which thing is causing delay. i sometime gets more download speed from internet and than through local LAN

Comment: Your domain is possibly pointing to your external IP address, so this traffic is going to the router, which is getting confused but sort-of handling it.  You might need to change the IP address associated with this site in the hosts files on your local PC [ to reflect the nat/rfc1918 address]

Answer (score 0):

Your modem/router will know its public IP, and will route local requests straight back to your network without going through to your ISP.  Try doing a traceroute to confirm that it never leaves your network:

```
tracert your.ip.add.ress
```